# Application Stopped: Code has no error on Android Studio but app does not run on phone

Tags: java, android, xml

My XML code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.dell.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="QUANTITY"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

My JAVA code is as follows:

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.dell.myapplication.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error on Android studio IDE but on uploading the APK file on my phone, it says "Application Error  Unfortunately, My Application has stopped."

How do I rectify this? Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Post your logcat..